Website unable to connect via Websockets (PHP)
I'm trying to create a working websockets project for myself. I'm unable to connect the client (the HTML/PHP file) to the server (the PHP file containing the serversocket).
I replaced my actual website URL with 'website.com' just for the Stack Overflow question.
Error message that I'm getting:
(index):13  WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.website.com/websocketServer.php' failed: 
Client (index.php):
<div id="root"></div>

<script>
    var host = 'ws://www.website.com/websocketServer.php';
    var socket = new WebSocket(host);
    
    
    socket.onopen = function(e) {
        console.log("CONNECTED!");
    }
    
    socket.onmessage = function(e) {
        document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = e.data;
    }
</script>

Server (websocketServer.php):
<?php

$address = "www.website.com";
$port = 0;

// Create WebSocket
$server = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($server, $address, $port);
socket_listen($server);
$client = socket_accept($server);

// Send WebSocket handshake headers
$request = socket_read($client, 5000);
preg_match('#Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)\r\n#', $request, $matches);
$key = base64_encode(pack(
    'H*',
    sha1($matches[1] . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')
));
$headers = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n";
$headers .= "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
$headers .= "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
$headers .= "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n";
$headers .= "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $key\r\n\r\n";

// Send messages into a WebSocket in a loop
while (true) {
    sleep(1);
    $content = 'Now: ' . time();
    $response = chr(129) . chr(strlen($content)) . $content;
    socket_write($client, $response);
}

?>


I'm not certain you are able to upgrade an HTTP connection in Apache/PHP to a web socket connection, but I could be wrong. Normally I see a dedicated web socket server running on the box listening for connections. The server (Apache, Nginx, IIS, etc.) is already "listening" to that host/path/port combination already, in an HTTP context.
